# Bootstrap a panel in Stata

Tags: stata

I want to use the Stata command `bootstrap` to block bootstrap an estimation method that includes group fixed effects. Although it is a user written command, I'll simply use `areg y x, a(id1)` in the examples below.

More precisely, I'm wondering how to compute

1. simple standard erorrs
2. standard errors clustered wrt `id1` (individual in a panel data setup)
3. standard errors clustered wrt `id2` that  encompasses `id1` (class instead of individual in a panel data setup)
4. standard errors clustered wrt `id3` that does not encompass `id1` (time instead of individual in a panel data setup)

I'm not sure I understand the options `cluster`, `idcluster`, and `group` and how they interact. For now, this is what I use

1. simple errors

   ```
    bootstrap, areg y x, a(id1)
   ```
2. error clustered wrt `id1`

   ```
    bootstrap, cluster(id1) newcluster(newid1): areg y x, a(newid1)
   ```
3. errors clustered wrt `id2` that encompasses `id1`

   ```
    bootstrap, cluster(id2) idcluster(newid2) group(id1): areg y x, a(id1)
   ```
4. errors clustered wrt `id3` that does not encompass `id1`

   ```
    bootstrap, cluster(id3): areg y x, a(id1)
   ```

Is this correct?

Comment: Is there any reason why you are using `areg` and not `xtreg, fe`?

Comment: Not really - I just wanted to make it clear the user written command (which is neither areg or xtreg) does not act on a panel (xtset) like xtreg, but requires a variable identifier, like areg.